# Tkinter Text Tag Config not persisting

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to colour every odd line in my Application, however I just have a line that is moving down the screen. Is this because I don't persist the tag?

Here is some of the code:

```
def addTextToRaw(self, text, changeColour=False, numberOfLines=0):
    self.rawText.config(state=NORMAL)
    self.rawText.insert(END,text)
    self.rawText.config(state=DISABLED)
    if changeColour is True:
        print "Changing Coloiur" + str(self.numberOfObjects())
        lastLine = int(self.rawText.index('end-1c').split('.')[0])
        start = str(lastLine)+".0"
        end = str(lastLine)+".0+"+str(1+numberOfLines)+"lines"
        self.rawText.tag_add("oddObject"+str(self.numberOfObjects()), start, end)
        self.rawText.tag_config("oddObject"+str(self.numberOfObjects()), background="blue", foreground="white")
```

This method is called using the after method which it gets data from a queue which is being processed.

None of the colour lines stay theres just one line moving down the screen. So what can i do to make the colours persist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the `tag_config` method in your update method this will then call it. Also you can give it the same tag so this method can be simplified like so:

```
def addTextToRaw(self, text, changeColour=False):
    self.rawText.config(state=NORMAL)
    if changeColour is True: 
        self.rawText.insert(END,text ,'oddObject')
    else:
        self.rawText.insert(END,text)
    self.rawText.config(state=DISABLED)
```

Then in the update method just call:

```
self.rawText.tag_config("oddObject", background="blue", foreground="white")
```

Comment: I don't understand your comment about configuring the tag in the update method. You only ever need to configure the tag once.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to color every other line, you merely need to add the tag once for each line, and you only need to configure the tag once when you create the widget.

Here's a working example:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.text = tk.Text(self, wrap="word")
        self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", command=self.text.yview)
        self.text.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)
        self.vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
        self.text.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

        self.text.tag_configure("odd", background="white", foreground="black")
        self.text.tag_configure("even", background="blue", foreground="white")

        self.addText(tk.__doc__)

    def addText(self, text):
        # get the starting line number
        index = int(self.text.index("end-1c").split(".")[0])

        # insert each line, adding a odd or even tag
        tag = "even" if (index%2 == 0) else "odd"
        for line in text.split("\n"):
            self.text.insert("end", line+"\n", tag)
            tag = "even" if tag == "odd" else "odd"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```